# Excel VBA/Formula for populating 3 specific cells based on the value of 2 other cells

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

In a workbook, I have a report set up as follows:

```
         A              B            C            D            E
1 Reporting Year        2012
2 Reporting Quarter     Q3
3                                 Jul-12        Aug-12       Sep-12
4
5
```

I’m trying to automate the population of cells C3, D3 and E3, based on what is selected in B1 and B2. For example, if B1 = 2012, and B2 = Q3, I’d like cells C3, D3, and E3 to populate with the months for that quarter in the format shown in the table. e.g. C3 = Jul-12, D3 = Aug-12 and E3 = Sep-12

Thanks in advance! I’ve tried to do something via named ranges, but it’s becoming very unwieldy and I’m sure there is a simpler way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One (of many!) alternatives:

```
=DATE($B1,SUBSTITUTE($B2,"Q",)*3+COLUMN()-5,1)
```

in C3 and copied across to E3, formatted to suit.

Could be simplified were B2 formatted `"Q"#`.

Comment: Thank you pnuts. This is exactly what I needed and works very well. Easy to figure out how you've done it too, and edit for different situations. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly easy to do with three simple formulas:

```
C3: =DATE(B1, (VALUE(RIGHT(B2, 1)) - 1) * 3 + 1, 1)
D3: =DATE(B1, (VALUE(RIGHT(B2, 1)) - 1) * 3 + 2, 1)
E3: =DATE(B1, (VALUE(RIGHT(B2, 1)) - 1) * 3 + 3, 1)
```

Then format your dates appropriately or use the `TEXT(C3, "MMM-YY")` function.

Alternative:

```
C3: =DATE(B1, VALUE(RIGHT(B2, 1)) * 3 - 2, 1)
D3: =DATE(B1, VALUE(RIGHT(B2, 1)) * 3 - 1, 1)
E3: =DATE(B1, VALUE(RIGHT(B2, 1)) * 3 - 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

in your VBA sheet module add the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim IntersectRng As Range
Dim Year As String, Quarter As String
Dim monthStart As Integer
Dim Months() As Variant

Set IntersectRng = Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B1:B2"))
Months = Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")

If (Not IntersectRng Is Nothing) Then

    Year = Range("B1")
    Quarter = Range("B2")

    Select Case Quarter

        Case "Q1"
            monthStart = 0
        Case "Q2"
            monthStart = 3
        Case "Q3"
            monthStart = 6
        Case "Q4"
            monthStart = 9
        Case Else

    End Select

    Range("C3").Value = Months(monthStart) & "-" & Year
    Range("D3").Value = Months(monthStart + 1) & "-" & Year
    Range("E3").Value = Months(monthStart + 2) & "-" & Year

End If
```